# Cannot fetch wcf service remotely

Tags: wcf, silverlight

i have 2 systems, one is localhost(Windows 8.1Pro) and another is Virtual Machine(Windows server 2008R2).
i have a silverlight app hosted in VM which is consuming WCF service from localhost installed in windows service.

**Problem:**

silverlight is not getting clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml so wcf service will not fetched.

**Tried solutions:**

1. Added clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml in WCF service solution before installing but still it can't be fetched from WCFservice url.
2. Added clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml in C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder, as per my search so many suggested to place their which will be automatically fetched by  silverlight.
3. tried adding clientaccesspolicy.xml code into wcf service as per this [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8392371/consuming-a-selfhosted-wcf-service-in-silverlight/) still no success.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Edit:**
okay i am attaching code FYR, i am doing this as below.

1. once i build WCFTest , 'll get .exe wcf installer which i am installing that using installutil.exe, so service'll be up and running in services.msc.
2. once i build TestSL, 'll get TestSLTestPage.html , on double clicking on this it'll open in IE, and on button click i should get "Hello World" from WCF.

[Download it from here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=96558361375491779079) and suggest me if i am doing anything wrong. Attached projects are of exact same structure as i am workinig on....

Regards,

Jithendra

Comment: any help??? that can solve my prob.

Answer (score 0):

as i explained my prob.above i was using self hosted Wcf service and i couldn't solve the problem so Here's what i did

```
1. Created Default WCF Service application in VS2013 with all my code and added clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml in the solution.
2. Created a new website in IIS Manager to publish my project.
3. and published my project to IIS as filesystem.
4. There we'll have all the files that are necessary.
```

And Voila everything works perfect.

Hope it helps somebody.